# Can IMetaDataImport resolve an RVA to a pointer?

Tags: .net, clr, portable-executable

I'm using the unmanaged .NET API and have come to the point where I want to obtain the CIL bytecode for a method. The IMetaDataImport interface can provide me with the RVA of the method implementation, but not the actual memory location as far as I've seen.

Is there a way to obtain the information without having to parse the PE headers myself? I know it's not so hard to do, but IMetaDataImport has already done it so that would be duplicating work.

If I really do have to parse the PE headers myself, can I obtain the HMODULE used by my IMetaDataImport instance or do I have to memory-map the file myself and call OpenScopeFromMemory to create my IMetaDataImport instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I worked with this API there was no built-in functionality for mapping an RVA to  an actual address. So yes, you have to map the file into memory yourself and parse the section table to find the section your RVA is in and read the base offset out of that. That value can then be added to your mapped image pointer to get to where the code is located in your memory mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about the API You mentioned, but reading it from a file or memory is easy if You have got RVA of method body.

Position in file can be calculated given You know Metadata header address in file or in memory, its RVA (field from CLR header) and RVA of a method (from MethodDef table in #~ stream).

```
offsetFromMetadataHeader = RVAofMethod - MetadataRVA
positionInFile = offsetFromMetadataHeader - positionOfMetaDataHeader
```

This one works in my implementation.

Metadata and bytecode are by default in the same section - .data.

For implementation of bytecode reading You might want to see Project Cecil on github (keep in mind you would have to deal with method header first).

Comment: I had already implemented some PE parsing by hand but I though I could fully transfer to using IMetaDataImport. I ended up resolving the RVAs myself. Are you sure about method RVAs being relative to the metadata header, though? I'm resolving them using regular PE image section headers and it works fine.

Comment: Edited to be more precise. I've made an assumption You've got file in-memory and already reading Metadata. Like I said, I haven't used that API.